# Disable arrow keys on input type="range"

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input like:

```html
<input type="range" id="sliderBarC" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0" oninput="SliderFunc('C');" />
```

And I would like to disable the user from using the arrow keys to move the slider.  How can I do this?  This does not work:

```html
<input type="range" id="sliderBarC" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0" oninput="SliderFunc('C');" 
       onkeypress="false" />
```

My slider controls equipment and I want to force them to slide with the mouse or their finger.

[image]

Comment: Whatever for? That just sounds like an accessibility problem.

Comment: @Quentin and this sounds like it's going to turn into an [X Y problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)

Comment: "My slider controls equipment and I want to force them to slide with the mouse or their finger" — What if they don't have a mouse? Or a finger for that matter?

Comment: I have the same question, and I have very good reasons for disabling the arrows, thank you. These comments are unpleasant and impolite.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting `onkeydown="return false;"` will do it.

```html
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" value="0" 
       onkeydown="return false;" />
```